# How to get parameter from url

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

I'm writing very simple Spring MVC application(just started to learn). It has only  one jsp page. After running this application(Im using Tomcat, not big deal) it has to show page with Hello and if I send some parameter to url(for example someURL/?name=mike) it has to be page with Hello mike

here is code

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class HelloController {
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String printWelcome(@RequestParam("name") String param, ModelMap model) {
        if (param == null || param.isEmpty())
            model.addAttribute("message", "Hello");

        model.addAttribute("message", "Hello " + param);
        return "hello";
    }
}
```

and hello.jsp:

```
<html>
<body>
    <h1>${message}</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem is if I there is not parameter in url, Hello page isnt shown, instead its error

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Can you post the `stacktrace` ?

Answer (score 1):

The [`@RequestParam`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestParam.html) annotation has a `required` attribute which you can set to `false` (it is `true` by default).

```
public String printWelcome(@RequestParam(value = "name", required = false) String param, ModelMap model) {
```

only in this case will Spring give you a `null` argument to a `@RequestParam` annotated parameter.

Comment: @John You are welcome. Consider upvoting the answers that were helpful and accepting one of them you considered most helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can set `defaultValue` parameter of `@RequestParam`. The default value to use as a fallback. Supplying a default value implicitly sets `required() to false`.

```
(@RequestParam(value = "name", defaultValue = "new value")String description)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your method name to include `required = false` for the name parameter, otherwise it is required by default, change your method signature to the following:

```
public String printWelcome( @RequestParam(value = "name", required = false) String param, ModelMap model)
```

From the Spring documentation:

> Parameters using this annotation are required by default, but you can
>   specify that a parameter is optional by setting @RequestParam's
>   required attribute to false (e.g., @RequestParam(value="id",
>   required=false)). http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html